# Android Layout Shapes

Tags: android, xml, layout

Is it possible to get the layout of the picture with XML. I need two of these side by side on one screen.

The left side will be displayed statically meaning from 1 to 24 with different color zones and the right side will be excactly the same but broken down into 24 pieces so I can manipulate them programmatically and define there order in which they appear.

I dont need it to be scrollable and it will be used on a variety of devices, so it must be flexible. The current implementation is with one image.jpg on the left and one other on the right through a imageView. The right picture is sliced into 24 jpg's and popullated dynamically.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71295596/demo.jpg

The protoype: https://www.fluidui.com/editor/live/preview/p_q1cf2aIWUbpBTobbPNQ61lF6xJcDG1gn.1430943636421

and my current xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="511dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/time24h" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/time_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0dp">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="#0f0" />
```

I tried to do something like the below but it doesn't show right.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="9"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_yellow_100"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_yellow_100"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_yellow_100"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="9"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_yellow_100"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_yellow_100"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_yellow_100"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>



    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I updated the main post for your questions. No I don't need an excel layout, I just made the example of the layout in excel and didn't delete the cells. I will try to make a more clear image and upload it.

Comment: I see your new image, but I'm still not sure what you want. May be, you could use a prototyping tool like https://www.fluidui.com/ and place some sample data into your prototype layout. Speaking abstractly about these things can be really difficult.

Comment: Made a protoype. On the left side it will be excactly the same static layout and never change. The right side shoulde be 24 views (or something else) so I can rearange them in java.

Comment: That's great! What are those items? List of products? Names of contacts? Pictures? Is this a game? Is only the column on the right scrollable? Does this mean that as soon as an item goes out of view at the bottom of the right column, it comes back on top of that column with the same background color? Also, do the proportions need to stay the same with phones with large heights and small heights? When I first read your description, I thought about something like that: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jpardogo.android.listbuddies (but now, I see that's not what you want).

Comment: Exact sample data would be super helpful. Are you afraid someone is going to steal your idea if you tell us exactly what this app is going to be for? and tell us what sample data it will contain?

Comment: Well not afraid for the idea, it's a horizontal clock, and the items are just numbers. So a simple textview did the trick. The tricky part is how can I arrange each textview on the right side based on some criteria. If you run the code below you will see what I mean.

Comment: Ha ok! By that, I think you meant to say a vertical clock (not horizontal). Something similar to the Timely Alarm screen? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.bitspin.timely&hl=en In which case, you may not even need an XML layout, you could everything with the Canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it right.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_image"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="25"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_black_1000"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Here"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_purple_500"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_purple_500"
            android:text="2"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_purple_500"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:text="3"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_purple_500"
            android:text="4"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_purple_500"
            android:text="5"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_purple_500"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:text="6"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_purple_500"
            android:text="7"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_teal_500"
            android:text="8"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_teal_500"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:text="9"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_amber_500"
            android:text="10"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_amber_500"
            android:text="11"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_amber_500"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:text="12"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_amber_500"
            android:text="13"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_amber_500"
            android:text="14"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_amber_500"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:text="15"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_amber_500"
            android:text="16"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_amber_500"
            android:text="17"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_brown_500"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:text="18"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_brown_500"
            android:text="19"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_brown_500"
            android:text="20"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_brown_500"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:text="21"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_brown_500"
            android:text="22"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_brown_500"
            android:text="23"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_brown_500"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:text="24"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="25"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_city"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_black_1000"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="New York"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_purple_500"
            android:text="1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_purple_500"
            android:text="2"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_purple_500"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:text="3"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_purple_500"
            android:text="4"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_purple_500"
            android:text="5"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_purple_500"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:text="6"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_purple_500"
            android:text="7"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_teal_500"
            android:text="8"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_teal_500"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:text="9"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_amber_500"
            android:text="10"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_amber_500"
            android:text="11"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_amber_500"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:text="12"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_13"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_amber_500"
            android:text="13"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_amber_500"
            android:text="14"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_15"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_amber_500"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:text="15"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_16"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_amber_500"
            android:text="16"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_17"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_amber_500"
            android:text="17"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_18"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_brown_500"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:text="18"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_19"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_brown_500"
            android:text="19"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_20"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_brown_500"
            android:text="20"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_21"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_brown_500"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:text="21"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_22"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_brown_500"
            android:text="22"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_23"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_brown_500"
            android:text="23"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour_24"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/md_brown_500"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:text="24"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>



    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```